# How to use EqualsVerifier in a Spock test

Tags: testing, junit, spock, equalsverifier

I have been writing my tests using spock. But to test Equals Hashcode contracts, I am trying to use [EqualsVerifier](http://www.jqno.nl/equalsverifier/). So my test code looks like:

```
def "test equals hashcode contract"() {
    EqualsVerifier.forClass(Content.class).verify();
}
```

But this does not look like its running with spock.

How can I workaround this? I wish to prefer using spock for my tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all works correctly but in spock it's a bit different, see:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')
@Grab('nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:1.7.2')

import spock.lang.*
import nl.jqno.equalsverifier.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def 'sample'() {
        when:
        EqualsVerifier.forClass(SomeClass).verify()

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}

class SomeClass {}
```

This *spec* fails since the exception **is** thrown - `SomeClass` needs to be corrected. Have a look at the great [docs](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html).

Comment: I did not need the Grabs - do you know why? FYI: I am building my project using maven.

Comment: Probably because you use maven or gradle and the dependencies are imported elsewhere? The script I provided is self runnable. You can save it to `whatever.groovy` and just run.